# Having issues with a regroup function in R

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to build a function that looks up a specific column in a dataset to easier generate bar plots from a flight delay dataset that I put together.

I've written the code to build a grouper function. It did not error out, so I wrote the code for my plot that I wanted to generate. When I ran it it claimed that it could not find the function 'regroup

```
GrouperFunc <- function(df, ...) df %>% regroup(list(...)) 

AirPlot <- function(departure, arrival, groupon){
    # Departure and arrival can be cities that are being entered.
    departCode <- AirportCode(departure)
    arriveCode <- AirportCode(arrival) # Call our earlier AirportCode function to get the airport ID 

    tempDB <- subset(flights, ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID == departCode & DEST_AIRPORT_ID == arriveCode) # Only get flights for our 
    grouped <- GrouperFunc(tempDB, groupon)                                                       # flight path
    # Use our GrouperFunc to have dplyr group our data into categories   
    summaryDF <- summarize(grouped, mean = mean(ARR_DELAY)) # Call summarize from our grouped data frame

    # Now that the data is in a good format, create the ggplot bar chart

    finalBarPlot <- ggplot(summaryDF, aes_string(x=groupon, y='mean')) +
        geom_bar(color="black", width = 0.2, stat = 'identity') +
        guides(fill=FALSE)+
        xlab(groupon) + 
        ylab('Average Delay (minutes)')+
        ggtitle((paste('Flights from', departure, 'to', arrival)))

    return(finalBarPlot)
}
AirPlot('Dallas', 'Chicago', 'UNIQUE_CARRIER')
 # Hide Traceback

 # Rerun with Debug
 # Error in regroup(., list(...)) : could not find function "regroup"
```

This should have a produced a bar plot giving me a mean delay by Carrier.

Comment: You appear to be using non-base packages. Besides `ggplot2`, what other packages are you using?

Comment: Nothing else other than ggplot2 and dplyr.

Comment: Forgive me for doubting that: `Error: object 'AirportCode' not found`, same for `AirPlot`. However, you appear to be using (or trying to use) an *old* version of `dplyr`: the `regroup` function was removed in 0.7.0 (ref: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md#dplyr-070).

Comment: Oh shoot... You're right. Time to go back to the drawing board...

Comment: (Sorry, the `AirPlot` error was my under-caffeinated moment.)

Comment: I get it... So, looks like I have to use group_by_ but then I can't use it as a list. I need to unlist it. To make it work. Not sure how to do this, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Where does `AirportCode` come from?

Answer (score 0):

As @r2evans told me, regroup is deprecated in the new dplyr version. Now we use group_by_ instead. So the code should look as such:

`GrouperFunc <- function(df, ...) df %>% group_by_(...)`

In other words,

**regroup(list(...))** becomes **group_by_(...)**

Comment: `group_by_` is deprecated as well, along with other `*_` verbs, in favor of using tidyeval